# Sending a error message from the controller to the view in ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am curious as to how to do this, I want to send a custom error message for forums **and** for regular views from a controller to a view (thus looking for examples of both). I have seen  `ModelState.AddError()` how ever I am looking to control the look the error message that is be able to wrap it in divs on the front end.

any ideas?

I am very new to ASP.net and the tutorials out there for this seem very confusing to me. So I don't really have any code to show as I am not sure what I am suppose to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking to customize the error message on your view. You can customize the error messages including the ones you added using `ModelState.AddModelError("", "error message")` in three ways.

### Option 1

Use `Html.ValidationSummary()` and customize its look via the `validation-summary-errors` class. The default mvc project template in VS will include that class by default. It has a default color of red (I think). But you can practically control every aspect of the error summary by changing that class.

```
.validation-summary-errors {
    border: 5px solid red; // thick red border
    color: #3904D9; // dark blue
    font-size: 1.5em; // quite big fonts
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

### Option 2

The `ValidationSummary` outputs the messages in an unordered list (`li`). If your project calls for a different way of showing the error messages, you can do it on the view by inspecting the `ViewDataDictionary`. The following code will write the error messages in separate divs with a thin red border. The style is written inline to make the sample simple.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData.ModelState) {
    if (item.Value.Errors.Any()) {
        foreach (ModelError e in item.Value.Errors) {
            <div style="border: 1px solid red;margin-bottom:5px;">
                @e.ErrorMessage</div>
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 3

If you do not want to put logic on your view, then you can extend the htmlhelper (or create a custom helper). You basically will use the same logic shown in Option 2 in the custom htmlhelper.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions {
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var html = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in helper.ViewData.ModelState)
        {
            if (item.Value.Errors.Any()) {
                foreach (ModelError e in item.Value.Errors) {
                    html 
                      += "<div style='border: 1px solid red;margin-bottom:5px;'>" 
                      + e.ErrorMessage 
                      + "</div>";
                }
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
    }
}
```

And then you use it the same way as you will use the `ValidationSummary`:

```
@Html.CustomValidationSummary()
```

Comment: I am wondering what you do to send a error from the controller to the view? is it ModelState.AddError()?

Comment: @TheWebs What exactly are you trying to do ? Form Validations ?

Comment: @TheWebs by using `ModelState.AddModelError`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the `ViewBag` object. If you set `ViewBag.ErrorMessage` in your controller, it will be available as a string in your view. And, actually, you can name it whatever you want, not just ErrorMessage.

Add this and include logic in your view to only display if `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)` and you should be good.

This is only one of multiple ways to do it. `ViewBag` is just a wrapper on `ViewData`, so if you are stuck, you may want to look into that object also.

While this answer is not fully comprehensive, hopefully it will give you a place to start.

Best of luck!!